# Why Windows does not check exists of folder of relative path?

Tags: php, linux, windows, relative-path, directory

Refer to the example below:

```
$path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/myapp/sessiondata_xxx/session_xxx_/../../code/doc/memo/index.csp";
var_dump(is_file($path), realpath($path));
```

Notes: The folder `sessiondata_xxx` and `session_xxx_` do not exits.

On Windows, the output is:

```
TRUE, "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/myapp/code/doc/memo/index.csp"
```

On Linux, the output is

```
False, False
```

So, **my question is**: Why Windows does not check exists of folders for the relative path?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: does `myapp/code/`  exist?

Comment: yes, /myapp/code/doc/memo/index.csp is exist

Comment: so then windows is kinda right, isn't it?

Comment: yup, I have no idea about this case. it's so strange. I searched, but no topic tell about this case. :((. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: In Windows the file system never sees the ".." component. That's resolved in the user-mode runtime library, in functions such as `RtlGetFullPathName_U` and `RtlDosPathNameToNtPathName_U`, which canonicalize the path purely as a string. This also affects the evaluation of symlinks, i.e. "symlink/.." will evaluate differently on Windows compared to Unix.

Comment: So, as I understand that on Windows, the path will be canonicalized before executing? It means that ".." and the previous folder will be removed firstly, so the system does not check whether the previous folder exists?

Comment: Most paths get resolved as a canonical DOS path and then converted to an NT path before getting passed to an NT system call. A canonical DOS path resolves all of the "." and ".." components, and trailing spaces and dots are removed from the final component. Also, certain DOS device names in the final component (ignoring the file extension) resolve to a device path (e.g. "C:\Temp\nul.txt" => "\\.\nul").

Comment: To convert to the NT namespace for a syscall such as `NtOpenFile` or `NtCreateFile`, a path that is at or below the working directory is made relative to the process working-directory handle. Otherwise it replaces "\\.\<device>" and "<X>:" DOS drives with "\??\<device_or_drive>" (e.g. "C:\Temp" => "\??\C:\Temp") and UNC "\\server\share" paths with "\??\UNC\server\share". NT's "\??\" prefix is a virtual union of its global and logon-session device paths, where the logon-session directory depends on the calling thread/process.

Comment: To bypass canonicalization and NT conversion, use a fully-qualified Unicode path that's prefixed by "\\?\". The RTL will simply copy the path to one that starts with "\??\" instead of "\\?\". This means you have to manually use the UNC device for UNC paths (e.g. "\\?\UNC\server\share"). If you use ".." components in a "\\?\" path, you will observe that NT's object manager does not reserve it and allows naming devices ".."  (e.g. via `DefineDosDevice`) and that file-system drivers are inconsistent. FAT32 confusingly allows creating a file named "..", but NTFS rejects it as an invalid name.

Comment: I understood. Thank you so much eryksun.